# How to get path with a string filename with digits within in Python?

Tags: python

I need to download a file that is automated on SharePoint. The thing is this file has the following filename structure:

`fileYYYYMmm.xlsb`

Example: `file2022M03.xlsb`

I must refer to this file using a wildcard or something (I don't know what exactly), to get dynamically that file.

Example: `file????M??.xlsb`

I'm using the following line code

```
download_path = sp.create_link(f'https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/GLB-GIS-PERISCPE/Shared%20Documents/TMS_Ch/file/file'+str(yy)+'M'+'??'+'.xlsb')
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with an [f string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).  You just need to reference the variable in curly braces like this:

```
the_year = '22'
the_month = '03'

# print(f'https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/GLB-GIS-PERISCPE/Shared%20Documents/TMS_Ch/file/file{the_year}M{the_month}.xlsb')
# https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/GLB-GIS-PERISCPE/Shared%20Documents/TMS_Ch/file/file22M03.xlsb

download_path = sp.create_link(f'https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/GLB-GIS-PERISCPE/Shared%20Documents/TMS_Ch/file/file{the_year}M{the_month}.xlsb')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you only need one file and you will have variable name for year and month

You can use [F-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) like this:

```
download_path = sp.create_link(f'https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/GLB-GIS-PERISCPE/Shared%20Documents/TMS_Ch/file/file{yy_var}M{mm_var}.xlsb')
```

Here `yy_var` will have store the year and `mm_var` will store the month.

Comment: The yy_var is necesarry but the mm_var is not. For example. In the folder there is just 1 file called file2022M02. It does not matter the month really.. just the year. I want to get the file using file file{yy_var}M**.xlsb').

Comment: Sorry then, I am not able to think of anything for this. worst case you can try looping over all 12 months if you dont find any solution

Comment: Is there any chance to tell python to download a file with an especific extension, for example .xlsb. It could be a solution instead.

Comment: You can't reference a url with a wildcard like this.  As manjy has said, you could if you know there are only 12 results, iterate 01 through 12 requesting the file each time and if you get a 404 you know to move on.  You've not said how you you are accessing Sharepoint but it might be a better approach to query the directory contents to get the name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN